# Can't disable usage of my on-site activity

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, privacy

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current

After clicking the page just refreshes, and I can't change this option.

> [image: Preferences page]

Comment: And why is there the big "Start Download" button there?  What would you be downloading?

Comment: have you blocked any supporting script domains? i think sstatic.com and cloudfront.com (not sure of exact domains sorry) cause the refresh when blocked. @Ward the button is for a copy of all the data currently stored for that purpose for your account, which is a legal requirement in some places.

Comment: @ocæon hello. No, I haven't blocked any specific domains.

Comment: indeed, i just checked and i'm getting the same behaviour! when i first joined i disabled it just fine, then re-enabled it as i didn't mind it and was curious to see what would change. now we're locked in! ~creepy music~

Comment: @ocæon no escape. We are doomed ＼(〇_ｏ)／

Comment: @Ward The download is in case you want to see the data SE has collected about you. It's just done in the name of transparency.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry about that. I just pushed a fix and it will be deployed with the next production build (at this rate, should be sometime tomorrow morning.)